# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'unmarshalType' is not allowed to appear in element 'jacksonxml'

Tags: jackson, jboss, apache-camel

I am tryng to use Jackson XML in a Camel Context. I have the following dependencies in my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jacksonxml</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Camel Context:

```
 <camelContext id="someid" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <dataFormats>
            <jacksonxml id="someid" unmarshalType="aclass"/>
        </dataFormats>
 </camelContext>
```

When i try to deploy the war on JBoss, i get the error above.

Comment: In Camel 2.x, the property is `unmarshalTypeName`. See https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/dataformats/json-jackson-dataformat.html

Comment: It's a good practice to have different version for camel-core and components. You should align everything to 2.16.0 or 2.10.1.